# Confirm is flickering

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I am trying to add a confirm on 1 event , it is working on firefox but not on chrome , earlier it was working on chrome as well but now not.

Now the confirmation box comes but soon it disappears, it flickers.

Below is the code for this:

```js
$('.job_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if (!confirm("If this job is posted to more than 1 person, it will go to the first person that accepts it.")) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<%= form_with(model: job, html: {"data-parsley-validate" => '', class: 'job_form'}, local: true) do |f| %>
  //  html fields
  <%= render partial: 'form2', locals: {f: f} %>
<% end %>
```

Below is form2

```
//html fields
<div id="isAllDiv"></div>

<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
 <%= f.submit 'Post Job', class: 'btn btn-primary signin-btn' %>

//html code with other fields
```

Output of executing **$._data( $(".job_form")[0], "events" );**

```
* {submit: Array(2), click: Array(1)}
    * click: Array(1)
        * 0:
            * data: undefined guid: 19 handler: ƒ (t)
                * guid: 19 arguments: (...) caller: (...) length: 1 name: "" prototype: {constructor: ƒ} __proto__: ƒ () [[FunctionLocation]]: parsley.min.self-78b…b2ddab.js?body=1:17 [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3] 
            * namespace: "Parsley" needsContext: false origType: "click" selector: "input[type="submit"], button:submit" type: "click" __proto__: Object 
        * delegateCount: 1 length: 1 __proto__: Array(0) 
    * submit: Array(2)
        * 0:
            * data: undefined guid: 18 handler: ƒ (t) namespace: "Parsley" needsContext: undefined origType: "submit" selector: undefined type: "submit" __proto__: Object 
        * 1:
            * data: undefined guid: 42 handler: ƒ (e) namespace: "" needsContext: undefined origType: "submit" selector: undefined type: "submit" __proto__: Object 
        * delegateCount: 0 length: 2 __proto__: Array(0) 
    * __proto__:
        * constructor: ƒ Object() hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty() isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf() propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable() toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString() toString: ƒ toString() valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
            * arguments: (...) caller: (...) length: 0 name: "valueOf" __proto__: ƒ () [[Scopes]]: Scopes[0] 
        * __defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__() __defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__() __lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__() __lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__() get __proto__: ƒ __proto__() set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Comment: window.confirm is not jQuery

Comment: The code does not get to the part you want to test now. Please update the HTML

Comment: You seriously need to understand what WE need to help you. I cannot run ROR so I cannot see what you see in your page. It is likely not a ROR issue at all  We need a [mcve] using PLAIN RENDERED HTML and any script and supporting CSS to reproduce the issue. If we cannot, then we cannot help. I cannot eye-ball debug your ruby code to see why JavaScript gives you a problem

Comment: 1 more finding that alerts are also flickering on 'onsubmit form'

Comment: I have created 1 js fiddle similar to above which is working but in my case its not

Comment: Perhaps share???

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach https://jsfiddle.net/kouh7dex/

Comment: So the fiddle should show the issue? I do not see it in Chrome on Win10

Comment: yes, the fiddle is not giving any error in my case as well, I am checking on macbook but when I integrate in my project , it givs

Comment: Sorry. Cannot help you then

Comment: If I add debugger in on submit function, then it stops and when I resume it, flicker doesn't comes

Comment: Did error reproduce in chrome from others PC? Maybe you have specific site settings in your project site? Please, found your site in chrome://settings/content/all and check it.

Comment: yes, other users have reported the same

Comment: do you have a function named `confirm` in your code somewhere? please search this keyword across the code as it may be clashing with `window.confirm`, also check the console of your browser if it is showing any errors or not.

Comment: No, I dont have confirm method in my code.
I guess some issue with data parsley on form because alert is also flickering on onsubmit

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma Check which other events are attached to the form: `$._data( $(".job_form")[0], "events" );`.

Comment: @saulotoledo Output of above is attached in the ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the following changes to make it working.
 1. I have changed the submit button to anchor tag:
 `<%= link_to 'Post Job', '#', id: 'submit_job' %>`

Then , I handled its clicked event and added a timeout in it:

```
$("#submit_job").on('click', function(){
  if ($('.job_form').parsley().validate()){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      if (!confirm("If this job is posted to more than 1 person, it will go to the first person that accepts it.")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
      $('.job_form').submit();
   }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by removing the e.preventDefault() or return false from the submit function. You cannot use it together

```
$('.job_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if (!confirm("If this job is posted to more than 1 person, it will go to the first person that accepts it.")) {
      e.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

Comment: tried but not worked, My code is working in firefox and earlier versions of chrome, it is also working in android chrome

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma Can you share the logs on chrome. And which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Chrome  Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I am not getting any error in chrome console for this

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma PLease share the gitlink

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update your way to submit. Add button and submit form on click of button

html

```
<form action = '#' method = "post" class = 'aa'>
  <input type = "text">
  <button id="button" type="button">
  Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

script

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
     if (confirm("If this job is posted to more than 1 person, it will go to the first person that accepts it.")) {
        $(".job_form").submit();
     }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69v8bsny/3/

Comment: i think this will work. becoz button will never try to submit for directly.

Comment: I also tried it, but no luck
$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
if ('aa').parsley().validate(){
if (!confirm('sure'){
e.preventDefault();
return false;
}})

Comment: you dont need to e.preventDefault or return false. you just need to put condition for submition of form like if (confirm('sure'){ $(".job_form").submit();}. And make sure your button has type="button"